# Add apm-server in helm with eck-operator

Tags: kubernetes, helm3, apm

We have an existing helm chart where we use to do helm install eck operator `docker.elastic.co/eck/eck-operator:2.0.0`
Then we have chart in which we have elasticsearch, kibana yaml file with roles and fluentd dependencies, Structure looks lie this
[image]

Now i'm **adding apm-server yaml file and hoping to get deployed along with other services, but its is not getting deployed**.

**apm-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apm.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: ApmServer
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  type: ApmServer
  version: {{ .Values.elasticStackVersion }}
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}
    #name: "es-cluster"
  kibanaRef:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}
    #name: "kibana"
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
        #- name: apm-server
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: 1
```

**values.yaml file**

```
elasticStackVersion: 8.0.0

elasticsearch:
  image: euaappcorecr.azurecr.io/elasticsearch
  replicaCount: 2
  storageClassName: default
  service:
    type: ClusterIP

kibana:
  image: euaappcorecr.azurecr.io/kibana
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "Lb_External_IP"

metricbeat:
  enabled: false
  image: euaappinfracr.azurecr.io/metricbeat


ApmServer:
  image:
    repository: euaappcorecr.azurecr.io/apm-server
    tag: 8.0.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  service:
    type: ClusterIP

fluentd:
  image:
    registry: euaappinfracr.azurecr.io
    repository: fluentd
    tag: bitnami-1.11.5
  forwarder:
    enabled: false
  aggregator:
    enabled: true
    configMap: elasticsearch-output
    persistence:
      enabled: true    
      storageClass: default
      size: 5Gi
```

cmd:  `helm install efk-dev . -n efk-dev --create-namespace --dependency-update -f values.yaml`

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/add-apm-server-in-helm-with-eck-operator/300997

Comment: What is Helm version? Do you receive any errors on deployment?